# JXBrowser stops loading when interact with JavaFX components

Tags: jxbrowser

**This only happens in Mac**

In the JavaFX Application if I displayed a ContextMenu or MenuItem the JXBrowser thread stops loading the webpage and when I dismiss them the page continue loading.

How can I avoid the JXBrowser thread stop loading a web page and interacting with JavaFX?

I'm currently using JXBrowser 6.9 but this also happens in previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use JxBrowser in heavyweight mode on Mac, the underlying Chromium engine runs inside Java process and uses the same AppKit thread as JavaFX. In case something blocks this thread, the Chromium engine is also blocked. I recommend that you use lightweight mode and multi-process architecture by setting "jxbrowser.ipc.external=true" VM parameter on Mac.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working perfectly but I leave the Lightweight mode I've just added the VM parameter

Comment: Where can I look for the set of all the VM parameters?. I'm trying to understand what exactly the jxbtrowser.ipc.external do